# Why would you use @JoinTable annotation instead of Unidirectional @OneToMany annotation within Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, hibernate-mapping

I am learning persistence with Hibernate (and JPA) on Udemy and the presenter explains an alternative to the previous associations discussed (unidirectional `OneToOne`, bidirectional `OneToOne`, Unidirectional `OneToMany`, bidirectional `OneToMany`), called the `@JoinTable` JPA annotation.

He mentions that sometimes only a small selection of the "Many" entities are associated with a specific kind of "One" entities and that we don't want a field on the "Many" entity to embody the association with the "One" entity since that field will remain null for most instances. **He goes on to recommend the `@JoinTable` for this situation**.

My question is, considering the effect of the `@JoinTable` option on the Java entities, why not just use the Unidirectional `@OneToMany` annotation on the "One" entity and leave the "Many" entity as-is? Which additional features would `@JoinTable` bring to the situation from within Java beyond what Unidirectional `@OneToMany` brings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then he is clearly wrong, `@JoinTable` is definitely not necessary here and will introduce overhead in terms of memory (more data to store) and time complexity (another table to join).

You're right about that you only need `@JoinColumn` to map one-to-one and one-to-many relationships (and `mappedBy` on the other side if it should be bidirectional).

P.S.: I would consider going further with this course, as it seems to be flawed even with the very basics of jpa.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, Andronicus. Without being too vague, I also would like to perhaps find out in which context/manner will a "@JoinTable" indeed be more useful than a Unidirectional "@OneToMany" annotation? Does the difference only pertain to the schema design or are there other significant advantages within Java?

Comment: @GerhardusduToit as I said, `@JoinTable` will not be more useful. It might be used in many-to-many relationship without mapping the joining table, where `@JoinColumn` is not applicable.